# how to get file download in swagger UI?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I need to generate a link in swagger in result which will download the file, but none of the solutions privded seem to work for me
see my code -

'''

```
[HttpGet]
/// <response code="200">success</response>
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, "Download a file.", typeof(FileContentResult))]
[Route("api/Controller/DownloadFile")]
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync("\\\\test-dm.com\\testfile\\" + fileName);
                return PhysicalFile("application/pdf", Path.GetFileName("\\\\test-dm.com\\testfile\\" + fileName));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var bytes = new byte[0];
                return File("text/plain", "test.pdf"); ;
            }
        }
```

'''

See my startup -

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "M2PPortal", Version = "v1" });
                
            });
```

[enter image description here][1]

see image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwcG1.jpg

i have seen only where other have download file link is coming, how should i configure for it.

This is my first question here, let me know if there are any issues in my query or any other info is required.

Comment: When you debug,will it go to `catch (Exception ex)`?

Comment: No, it returns a reply just no link for downloading files shows up.

Answer (score 0):

[See result image, which was as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znesT.jpg)Using below code gave the expected result, basically a link to the file -

```
 [HttpGet]
        /// <response code="200">success</response>
        [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, "Download a file.", typeof(FileContentResult))]
        [Route("api/Controller/DownloadFile")]
        public FileContentResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_configuration.GetValue<string>("FilePath:PathofFiles") + fileName), "application/pdf", fileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // write a generic return value which could be used to handle error
            }
        }
```

using FileContentResult instead of action or ActionResult  or HttpResponseMessage.
No changes where required in Configureservices or configure